# Raising exceptions in Python

Tags: python, exception

I am reading from an e-book, here is my code:

```
import math

class QuadError( Exception ):
    pass

def quad(a,b,c):
    if a == 0:
        ex = QuadError( "Not Quadratic" )
        ex.coef = ( a, b, c )
        raise ex
    if b*b-4*a*c < 0:
        ex = QuadError( "No Real Roots" )
        ex.coef = ( a, b, c )
        raise ex
    x1= (-b+math.sqrt(b*b-4*a*c))/(2*a)
    x2= (-b-math.sqrt(b*b-4*a*c))/(2*a)
    return (x1,x2)
```

Although I understood the try... except thing inside a function, I can't understand this...
I understand what it does, e.g I have used quad(4, 2, 4) that gives me an "No Real Roots" error, or the quad(0, b, c)
However I can't understand how the program itself works...
So,

```
if a == 0:
```

a varibale with the name: "ex", gets the value: QuadError( "Not Quadratic" )
so the programs searches for the Class QuadError that has a pass command in it???! Then why does it print the message??? I would expect something like...

```
class QuadError( Exception ):
    print Exception
```

Next thing I don't unserstand is the line:

```
ex.coef = ( a, b, c )
```

What's that???
is coef a command? Does it do something?

Thanks guys! :)

Comment: Are you familiar with classes in general, and inheritance in particular? It may be better to postpone learning about this until you learn about that.

Comment: I do know both! However, I read about them about 7 months ago, but I think I do remember...

Comment: `QuadError(Exception)` inherits from Exception, which means that it gets all the fancy goodies that come with the Exception class.  Including the ability to act like any standard exception.  the `pass` keyword is just a control flow statement of sorts that says, no more after me. and ex.coef is being assigned a tuple of a,b,c.

Comment: if you don't understand `ex.coef = ( a, b, c )`, you need to go back to basics.

Comment: I really don't... I studies classes some months ago, I didn't right now, but the book just has the above code in the Exceptions section. I 've got no idea what's wrong...

Comment: i'll help though: `ex.coef = ( a, b, c )` is simply assigning the tuple `a, b, c` to `ex.coef`. later, when you're examining the exception, you can see what inputs caused the exception (by looking at `coef`)

Comment: I see! It's something I meet for the 1st time... How do I look at coef?

Comment: print ex.coef won't work

Comment: @midkin After the Exception is raised, the code exits. Since this was in a function, all local variables are lost after the function terminates (whether through an exception or returning), To access it, do   
`try:`    .
`    quad(a, b, c)`     .
`except QuadError as ex:`    .
`    print ex.coef`

Comment: Isn't try: also gonna be inside a function? :?

Comment: @midkin But the exception is caught and stored in a variable (`ex`). This way, you can access it without changing a function. Put the try outside the function, so you can catch the QuadError and using the `except Error as variable`, can access all it's attributes.

Comment: let me try a program, without a function and i text again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is a definition of a class derived from `Exception`, also known as a subclass of it. The body of it is empty (it adds no new behavior or attributes to the base class), so the statement `pass` is used because class bodies have to have something in them.

```
class QuadError(Exception):
    pass
```

In this part of the code:

```
ex = QuadError( "Not Quadratic" )
ex.coef = ( a, b, c )
raise ex
```

it's creating an instance of the new class and passing it a string which will become the exception's `message` attribute and be displayed if the exception is printed. The `ex.coef` assignment adds an attribute of that name with the value of which is tuple with the coefficients values. This isn't very useful by itself, however other code could try to access the added attribute and use the values somehow. There's no example of doing that in your code however.

In my option it might be better to add the coefficient values to the exceptions message itself so they would be printed along with one.

This is what I mean:

```
a, b, c = 0, 1, 2
try:
    ex = QuadError("Not Quadratic: coefficients a:{} b:{} c:{}".format(a,b,c))
    raise ex
except QuadError as qe:
    print(qe)
```

Output:

```
Not Quadratic: coefficients a:0 b:1 c:2
```